# double AND clause

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm getting the first **WHERE** and **AND** clause but the second 
**AND** clause is not.

```
  private void LoadOrders()
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select quo_product,quo_address
                            FROM JobQuotations
                            WHERE quotationId = @id
                            AND quo_product = @product
                            AND quo_verified = 'yes';",con);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);

            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(rdr.Read())
            {
                lblProductName.Text = rdr["quo_product"].ToString();
                lblAddress.Text = rdr["quo_Address"].ToString();
            }

        con.Close();
    }
```

I should recieve an output where all `quo_verified` which column value is = **yes**,but I'm also recieving a column value which is = **no**

Comment: What is the `quo_verified` data type in the database? Also, you can remove the semi-colon I think `;`

Comment: Could you double-check that you get `quo_verified='no'` rows by reading `quo_verified` and printing it as you read from `rdr`? You shouldn't get anything but `'yes'` in that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the `quo_verified` data type in the database. Some conversion due to unmatching data type with the database's table's column may cause the issue.

That being said, you might want to make all parameters parameterized to ensure that there is nothing wrong in the C# side. You could also remove the semicolon `;`:

```
private void LoadOrders()
{
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand(@"Select quo_product,quo_address
                        FROM JobQuotations
                        WHERE quotationId = @id
                        AND quo_product = @product
                        AND quo_verified = @yes",con);

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product", GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yes", "yes");

    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while(rdr.Read())
    {
        lblProductName.Text = rdr["quo_product"].ToString();
        lblAddress.Text = rdr["quo_Address"].ToString();
    }
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm still getting a `quo_verified = no` output.

Comment: what is the data type? It is most likely the issue since you have done what you should in C#. For instance, string or char can be auto-converted to int in the database

Comment: Please show some of your database entry too, I think it might help better. There is nothing wrong in the C# code as far as I can tell.

Comment: Ok wait a sec.I think I figured it out now.

Comment: I figured out It was on my other class that have to use the double and clause.The class which output the datagrid.It's working fine now.

Comment: @rainalasa OK, great to know that. :)